# How to remove the flush mount ceiling fixture

Tags: ceiling, light

I am trying to change the bulb in the ceiling fixture as shown in the pic.
However, it is not easy to remove the fixture. I twisted the cover counterclockwise but I could not make it. Please help me to remove the fixture.

This is Satco S21507 (https://www.satco.com/s21507.html)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to DIYSE. You twisted the fixture housing, or you *tried* to twist it? I'd expect that you'd twist counter-clockwise to disengage some bumps from some slots. It could also be simply a clip-on arrangement, where you pull downward.

Comment: Thanks, Isherwood, I actually twisted it a bit but I could not feel any bumps to get hint to remove. And I also tried to pull it down with some strength of my fingers but it is tightly stuck there, from my feeling. The product homepage is saying that the base is "Connector" which I do not understand.

Comment: I'd say this is one of the newer flush mount LEDs that mounts to a standard lightbox and not a can housing.

Comment: The manufacturer was kind enough to provide an email link. At this point, I'd use it.

Comment: Try placing your hand flat on the white diffuser part only (not the outer housing) and twist, but as others have stated - that fixture doesn't have a replaceable bulb inside. If you do get it open you'll find a flat circuit board with a number of LEDs surface-mount soldered to it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the "bulb" can be replaced as it doesn't contain a bulb. This fixture is only 1" deep. It most likely has a hardwired LEDs. I looked at the specs for this fixture at the link you provided and also downloaded and viewed the PDF specs. There's nothing mentioned about bulb replacement. I installed a similar fixture several weeks ago. The diffuser "globe" is what you should be trying to remove, not the trim ring.

Comment: Thanks, Bill, I really appreciate for your response. then I may need to remove diffuser globe as you mentioned. But still I do not know how to remove it.

Comment: See @brhans comment on your initial post. And you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with others that there is no replaceable bulb inside - all you can do is replace the whole thing. Satco might replace it for free under warranty - their site says 5-year. Also ask them how to remove it: consumers@satco.com

Answer (score 0):

Per @isherwood suggestion

The backside *might* look like this:

[image]

Comment: This is a retrofit integrated led insert for a recessed ( can ) light and not flush mount as depicted by the OPs pic.